# redirect(url_for()) passing parametrs doesn't work

Tags: python, flask

whenver I pass a parameter using redirect and url_for, it addes them to the url but not showing them in the html. If I use render_template and passing parameters it's working as it should.

My Code:

```
@app.route("/forgotpass", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def forgot_password():
    if session["logged_in"] == True:
        return redirect(url_for("profile"))
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form["username"]
        email = email.lower()

        logins.forgotPassword(email)

        return redirect(url_for("login", error = "We have sent you an email with your new password!"))
    
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("forgotPassword.html")
```

HTML:

```
<p>{{ error | default('') }}</p>
```

Does anyone know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how `url_for` works, you can pass parameters/variables to it and those will be added to the URL, it is not made for displaying errors.

If you want to display messages to user, for example after successful login or when login fails, you should use Message Flashing instead: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/

Example code, import `flash` from flask first:

```
@app.route("/forgotpass", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def forgot_password():
    if session["logged_in"] == True:
        return redirect(url_for("profile"))
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form["username"]
        email = email.lower()

        logins.forgotPassword(email)

        flash('We have sent you an email with your new password!')

        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("forgotPassword.html")
```

Put this somewhere in your login template:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class="flashes">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```